# Change header on HTTP before retrying an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript on the front-end. I am trying to implement a http interceptor that is setting the authorization header on each request. If the access token expires I am trying to retry the request, get a new access token with the refresh token and change the header of the current request, before the retry.

How to update the request header in the retryWhen operator?

For example here is the HttpInterceptor:

```
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.get(url, this.setRequestAuthorizationHeader(options)).retryWhen((errors: any) => this.errorHandler(errors));
    }

    private setRequestAuthorizationHeader(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        // some checks
        // get accessToken from localStorage
        options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    }

    private errorHandler(errors) {
        return errors.switchMap((err) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
            let closedSubject = new Subject();

            this.authenticationService.refreshToken()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    // How to update authorization header? This doesn't work.
                    this.defaultOptions.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + data.accessToken);

                    closedSubject.next();
                });

            return <any>closedSubject;
        }
        else {
            return Observable.throw(err.json());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Beware that using an external service to refresh the token (I guess `authenticationService` uses Http too), you will end up in circular dependency `HttpInterceptor` needs `authenticationService` that needs `HttpInterceptor`.

Comment: Thanks, n00dl3. I am loading the Http in authenticationService dynamicly with the injector.

Comment: could you add the authentication service code ?

Comment: I would use `catch` instead of `retryWhen`, the later one will replay the same `Observable`...

Comment: There is nothing special in refreshToken method. Building the token request and make a request:

`return this.http.post(path, data, { headers: headers })
            .map(response => response.json());`
If you want to see how I inject the http, here it is:

`constructor(private injector: Injector...) {} 
private get http() { this.injector.get(Http); }`

Comment: btw why using a subject in errorHandler o_Ô ?

Comment: If you have 4 parallel requests, and all of them have expired token, then all of them will run refreshToken(). Right? This is very confusing because 4 requests will make 4 refreshToken with the same token. 1 will return the right token and the other 3 requests will fail. Right? Am I wrong? What is the solution?

Comment: @Michalis that's correct. If you solved the issue, please share. I've not worked on this problem, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `catch` instead of `retryWhen` as the latter one replay the same observable, and the parameters have already been set.

BTW, your Subject is useless in `errorHanlder` :

```
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
  get(url: string, options ? : RequestOptionsArgs): Observable < Response > {
    return super.get(url, this.setRequestAuthorizationHeader(options)).catch(errors => this.errorHandler(errors, url, options))
  });
}

private setRequestAuthorizationHeader(options ? : RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
  // some checks
  // get accessToken from localStorage
  options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  return options
}

private errorHandler(err: any, url: string, options ? : RequestOptionsArgs) {
  if (err.status === 401) {
    return this.authenticationService.refreshToken()
      .switchMap(data => {
          // save accessToken to localStorage
          return super.get(url, this.setRequestAuthorizationHeader(options));
      });
  }
  return Observable.throw(err.json());
}
```

Also note that using state like `this.defaultOptions` is probably not your best choice, using anobservable would be more appropriate.

Comment: How do you get `url` and `options` in the `errorHandler`? If I make a new request with the url and options with the new auth header I will lose the subscribers from failed request that I want to be executed after the request is done. That's why I am trying to do it with retryWhen.

Comment: " If I make a new request with the url and options with the new auth header I will lose the subscribers that I want to be executed after the request is done." ---> definitely not .

Comment: for `url` and `option` you can pass them in the parameters. I edited.

Comment: Okay... So the returned observable in the errorHandler will combine with the old observable and the data from the new request will be pushed to the subscribers to failed request? Am I right?

Comment: that's it, if `catch` is reached, observers will get data from the observable it returns.

Comment: Thank n00dl3. I'll try it.

Comment: Interesting thing is that `errors` has no `switchMap`: `e.switchMap is not a function`.